# What would a biography on an animal be called?

Tags: terminology, genre, biography

If biography means:

- an account of someone's life written by someone else.
- biographies as a branch of literature.
- a human life in its course.

What would a biography based on a particular animal be called?

Comment: There have been biographies of completely inanimate objects, such as books. E.g. [The Talmud: A Biography](https://books.google.com/books?id=5nxGDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+talmud+a+biography&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKmfmH2qneAhWuhOAKHemvAf4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [The Bible: The Biography](https://books.google.com/books?id=JtMaTD-dA30C&dq=the+bible+a+biography&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwh73V2aneAhXjg-AKHR3CBUAQ6AEIMDAB).

Comment: Ah, ok, so it sounds like you can use biography in general to describe writing about something? When would it be more appropriate to use memoir?

Comment: I would say *zoography*, but it seems that the word is [already taken](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zoography)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Biographies of animals are not a very common genre, although it is not difficult to find examples with a bit of digging:

- [*Flush: A Biography*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flush:_A_Biography) (1933) by Virginia Woolf is the "imaginative biography" (Wikipedia's description) of a dog. Its [entry in the Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/2009464725)) simply classifies is as "biographical fiction".
- *Bobbie, a Great Collie* by Charles Alexander (1926) is about [Bobbie the Wonder Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobbie_the_Wonder_Dog). The [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/26009759) does not identify the book's genre.
- *Comanche: Story of America's Most Heroic Horse* (1951) by David Appel is about of one of General Custer's horses. Its [entry in the Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/51005190) does not mention a genre.
- *Reckless, Pride of the Marines* (1955) by Andrew Geer is about [a war horse that served in the Korean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergeant_Reckless). Neither the [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/55005642) nor Amazon.com provide genre information for this book.
- *Soldier Bear* (1970) by Geoffrey Morgan and Wiesław A. Lasocki is about [a bear named Wojtek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wojtek_(bear)) that was enlisted in the Polish II Corps. The [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/70583187) does not specify the book's genre but considers it as **"juvenile literature"** (see "LC subjects").
- *The Judy Story: The Dog with Six Lives* (1973) by Edwin Varley is a book about [a ship's dog in the British Royal Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_(dog)). The Library of Congress does not know it; Amazon.com only has it second-hand and does not classify it as any specific genre. *Judy: A Dog in a Million* (2014) by Damien Lewis is a more recent book about the same dog. Neither the [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/2014456926) nor Amazon.com provide genre information for this book.
- [*Dewey: The Small-Town Library Cat Who Touched the World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey:_The_Small-Town_Library_Cat_Who_Touched_the_World) (2008) by Vicky Myron is the "biography" of [Dewey Readmore Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Readmore_Books), the [library cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_cat) of the Spencer Public Library in Spencer, Iowa. The [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/2008004498) does not classify this book as biography (but it has "Library cats--Iowa--Spencer--Biography" listed as a subject). Amazon.com lists it under "Books > **Biographies & Memoirs** > Regional U.S. > Midwest". Wikipedia's editors have not bothered tagging the article about the book with anything referring to "biography".
- *Hachiko : the true story of a loyal dog* (2004) by Pamela S. Turner in the [Library of Congress](https://lccn.loc.gov/2002155546) does not have a genre identification, but the term "biography" is used in the "LS Subjects" ("Dogs--Japan--Tokyo--Biography.").

A biography of an animal *can* be called in **"animal biography"**. However, books about animals are sometimes classified as "juvenile literature", sometimes as "biography", depending on the audience rather than the individual whose live is being described. I have never come across the term "animal biography" in a dictionary of literary terms and don't expect it to become a literary term in the near future.

Comment: One more point in favour: [*Hachiko: The true story of a loyal dog*](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=1317&recCount=25&recPointer=6&bibId=13029911), which, if I understand correctly, is classified as a biography.

Comment: @muru Thanks. I have added Hachiko to the list.

Comment: Not a very common genre? Either I have some quite specific reading tastes, or my idea of a "biography" isn't strict enough. I must have read a dozen or so books/series which could (at least arguably) be called biographies of animals.

Comment: @Randal'Thor A sample of one is not what I would call a representative sample ;-) "Common" is based on the total output of fiction, not on what a specific reader has read.

Comment: I know, hence my first conclusion that I have some quite specific reading tastes :-)

Answer (score -2):

It would be called an animal biography or juvenile literature.

Comment: While that makes sense (except maybe for the juvenile literature part), are there any examples of books being listed under "animal biography"? The other answer here couldn't find any.